# How do I know if it's the latest version of my application that is running on the emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, version, apk

I develop an Android application using Eclipse and the Android emulator. Sometimes I don't know if I am running the latest version of my application in the emulator. Is there any way I can check if it is the latest version?

E.g. I do a change of the layout for my application, but when I run the application in the emulator and the change isn't visible. Then I don't know if it is an old version of the application that is running or if I have done something wrong in the new version so the change isn't visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor your console output as it tells you if the application was installed or not and of course keep an eye on the emulator itself as you will see your application close and reopen when it gets installed.

Comment: Thanks, I did the mistake to close the emulator between every run. Now is it more intuitive to see when the new version is running.

Comment: Closing the emulator is definitely overkill. I just close my app by hitting the home button. That way, if my app is running, it must be the newest (or I forgot : )