# Android: Eclipse doesn't pushed new version of app to emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

When developing for Android in Eclipse, the emulator relaunches the old version of the app each time I run the project unless I go through the rather arduous procedure of *Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> [my application] -> Uninstall -> Ok -> Ok* in the emulator.

I had this problem on some projects but not on others when following the tutorials on the Android Developers site, and my friend turns out to have the same problem. Although this has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602537/android-restarting-with-a-fresh-version-of-the-app-being-developed) and to some extent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144131/how-do-i-know-if-its-the-latest-version-of-my-application-that-is-running-on-the)) their problem turned out to be "some extra quotes on one of the xml file" and I can see no such thing in my project. Otherwise people seems to be saying that Eclipse *should* push the new version. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue as well, and what i figured out was:

If you are using your device for debugging, then you should launch a `debug session`, not a run one.

On the other hand, if you want to install an application, or you want to launch a `run session` directly on your device, the `version` of your application set in the `androidManifest.xml` must be greater than the one on your phone.

Comment: +1 I'd noticed this occasionally myself, thanks for the explanation

Comment: I believe the version only needs to be increased for updating signed apps. Other wise the console will give an error if you have a lower number than what is already installed

Comment: @Wayner, based on the documentations, you're completely right. I was just sharing my observation. There was no error in my logcat, but my app did not get updated on the device when I launched in run mode with the same version number. Might be an eclipse issue, but when I either increased the version number or launched in debug mode, the application got updated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try Menu-Project-Clean, Select your project to clean, this will delete everything but the source. Eclipse should re-build automagically if not select Menu-Project-Build Automatically.
2. Right click your project, Android tools, fix project should automatically fix some unknown error maybe
3. Double check your xml, an error in a layout could cause your situation. A wrong id for example will not show as an error in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! The first option (Cleaning the project) actually works most of the time, alas not always, and I have not really been able to discern a pattern for when it does and when it doesn't :s