# Old copy of application appears on Android Emulator (using Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm using Eclipse and the Android plug-in for my Android phone development.  I just worked through my first application from the "Busy Coder's" book and I'm having a persistent problem.  Every time I run the example Java application, using a properly configured Android Run configuration that references the example project, the emulator starts (if not already started) and the application is seemingly deployed to the emulator.  However, what shows on the emulator is not a reflection of the application's current state.  Specifically, the example application I typed up should display the current time and then every time you click on the main app view area it should update the current time (via a Button object instance created in the constructor that has an onClick() handler).  Instead, I see "Hello World" and clicking on the main view area does nothing.

It's as if some old copy of the test application is being pulled up.  I even hunted down the strings XML file for the project and I did find a string declaration that was defined to "Hello World".  I then changed that string to something else, rebuilt the project, and re-launched the application.  But I still got the same "Hello World" display and still do not get any response when clicking on the main view area.  I even tried shutting down Eclipse and the emulator and nothing changed, and also cleaning the project before a test run.

So, what are the usual mistakes a newbie makes that could cause this situation?

-- roschler

Comment: I'm having the same problem at times, I think it has something to do with enabling "snapshot" in the emulator. But not sure yet. Usually recompiling fixes it for me, though.

Comment: Note that you can always uninstall the application on the running emulator, just like you'd uninstall an application on a real Android device.  Also, if you "manually" launch the emulator with the Android SDK and AVD Manager (through the Eclipse Window menu), you have the option to select to "Wipe user data", which would also ensure an old version of the app is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens to me occasionally but it is usually fixed by deleting the application from within the emulator UI.

After deleting the application from the emulator and reinstalling it I can launch the application using "Run". After this the application is updated every time the "Run" button is used.

Check the console to see if the activity is actually being installed and launched rather than being brought to the front when you "Run" the app.

Answer (score 2):

If you launch in debug mode, the new build will always be installed in the emulator/device.

However, if you launch in run mode, you need to increase the version number in AndroidManifest.xml, or the new version won't always get installed.

Please see [Android: Eclipse doesn't pushed new version of app to emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680433/android-eclipse-doesnt-pushed-new-version-of-app-to-emulator/5680491#comment-6485700) from earlier today.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: This is simply not true.  I regularly launch in run mode without updating the Manifest, and don't have a problem - the new version of the app is always installed, replacing the old version of the app.

Comment: @Thane Experiences vary. Other people have run into this issue and solved it by increasing the version number. Have you encountered/fixed this issue, other than by re-installing?

Answer (score 0):

By far the most common reason this happens to me is that I failed to notice that there was an error compiling the application so it didn't push the new version.  Especially when my package explorer is obscured so I don't notice the red X.
Edit: one other reason it often happens to me is I have more than one emulator running or my phone or tablet plugged, and I accidently install the latest version to the wrong device without paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

I open the manifest file in Eclipse, "touch" it by deleting and undeleting something, save it. This seems to refresh the APK for me.